# Custom Home Button In ArcGIS API for Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/koL9kyq5/) and let me know how I can set up a custom home button

```js
    var map;
    require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/graphic", "dojo/dom","dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map, Point,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
    Graphic, dom, on) {
            map = new Map("map", {
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 5,
            basemap: "topo",
            slider: false, // set to false to remove default zoom buttons
            spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
        });
        on(dom.byId("zoomInBtn"), "click", function(evt){map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);});
        on(dom.byId("zoomOutBtn"), "click", function(evt){map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);});
        on(dom.byId("goHome"), "click", function(evt){});
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "goHome" function can just use the centerAndZoom function as described in the [API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerandzoom). So the code for your function procedure would be:

```
map.centerAndZoom([0,0],5);
```